# Determine fallback UIFont for special characters in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uifont

I'm using `Averta` font series in my iOS app. I'm trying to show "₿" symbol in `Averta-Bold`. When there is unsupported character, iOS show it in default system font. I don't have any problem with showing unsupported characters with default system font. However, It is showing with wrong weight. **My problem** is that It is showing symbol in **regular** system font not in **Bold** system font.

**My Question is that** how can I set fallback font when character is not supported use system font with **same** weight.

P.S: I don't wanna use `NSAttributedString` and custom fallback methods. I'm in search of overriding default iOS behavior.